# Why does the while loop keeps looping even when the object reference value changed and the break statement should execute?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, methods, console

after executing the command `sw.start()`, when I run `sw.stop()` which would change the value to `running.value = false` and the break statement should execute cause the `running.value` is false but that doesn't happen...

It isn't exactly a Stopwatch, rather stop calculating program gone wrong, :)

some weird things that happen when I run this script in the console:

- when I run sw.stop(), it works
- when I run sw.resetit(), it works
- sw.duration() also works
- when I run sw.start() maybe it starts the calculations
  but after that when run any other commands the console doesn't take any input or respond, I have to pause the script from running from the source dev tools and then it shows the output of other commands if I had entered any after it stopped responding. But after entering sw.start(), the console doesn't respond.
- Anyways, is there any way, by which I could write another method, that somehow stops the start() method.
- **In other words could I write a function and then call it from a method to start and then stop it from another method.**

```
function StopWatch(){
    let current = {t:0};
    let running = {value:false};

    //this function doesn't stop somehow
    const timmy = () => {while(true){
        current.t += 0.01;
        if(running.value===false){
//this block never runs??
            console.log(`stopping...`);
            break;
            }
        };
    }
    this.start = function(){
        if(running.value === true){
            throw new Error('It is already running');
        } else {
            running.value = true;
            //timer will go here
            timmy();
        }
    }
    //stop doesn't seem to work
    this.stop = function(){
        if(running.value === false){
            throw new Error(`It's is not running.`);
        }
        else {
            running.value = false;
            console.log(running.value);
            //i hope this works
            //
        }
    }
    
    this.resetit = function(){
        if(current.t === 0){
            throw new Error(`It's all ready reset`);
        }
        else{
            current.t = 0;
        }
        
    }
    
    this.duration = function() {
        return `${current.t}s`;
    }
}
const sw = new StopWatch();
```

some questions you don't have to answer:

could I write a function and then call it from a method to start and then stop it from another method.

How to stop a function which loops by calling another function, which changes the value of an object or variable, which if set to 'false' will then stop the function that loops because the function is looping on the object or variables value which is true or false?  it is even possible??

Comment: [What is the X Y Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: Well the real problem is : why when I run the `stop()` method, does the `while()` loop doesn't break? In the `stop()` method I change the value of `running.value = false;` but still the while loop keeps executing, and the console doesn't respond, and I have to pause the script. Thnx for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

This is causing the problem:

```
 const timmy = () => {
    while(true){ // --> never stops
        current.t += 0.01;
        if(running.value===false){
         //this block never runs??
         console.log(`stopping...`);
         break;
        }
   };
 }
```

run the loop while running.value is true:

```
const timmy = () => { 
   while(running.value){
      current.t += 0.01;
   };
}
```

Comment: I figured out the problem: it's the nature of the while loop (or the chrome console) to not take any inputs until the while loop finishes executing. I tried writing a small piece of code to check if the console takes input while it's executing the while loop. And it doesn't

Comment: `let button = { v: true };
let a = 1;

let bc = { v: false };
let ls = () => {
  bc.v = true;
  console.log("ls was called and now bc.v =" + bc.v);
};

let frvr = () => {
  while (button.v) {
    a += 1;
    if (a === 9999) {
      console.log("value of bc.v was " + bc.v);
      button.v = false;
    }
    console.log("the loop is running...");
  }
  console.log("the loop has ended");
};
` here's the code if you want to try...

Answer (score 0):

**While loop** always executes the code **at least once**.

So when you run StopWatch(); for **first-time it will not execute** correctly
if you try it running stopwatch(); twice it will be working.

So coming to the point,

we have to use

> If-Condition within the while loop

so it will check the condition and
executes in the correct direction.